# How can pass the user name / password to iOS external browser for authentication?

Tags: iphone, ios, authentication

Greeting everyone, may I ask your help for following question?

I'm using following code to call external browser in my current iPhone apps:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urls];
```

- urls = "http://myhost.net/home.aspx"

Assume user is already logged in to the apps,
I can to pass the user name password to "home.aspx" if security is not a concern...
e.g. urls = "http://myhost.net/home.aspx?username=xxx&password=123456"

Question 1: Can I pass some information to home.aspx by "post" instead of "get" method?

Question 2
If above solution is not possible, I would like to set basic authentication in IIS 7.
When the external browser called by apps, can users access to "home.aspx" without 2nd login? (e.g. use code to bypass it)

For Q2, here is my current situation for your reference:

1) I have video steaming service provided by Windows IIS, when user type the URL from browser, the login form will prompt. a. e.g. xxxx/video.htm b. The IIS is configured with SSL and basic authentication

2) After user login succeed, the video should be properly displayed in the HTML 5 page.

3) We have the iPad/iPhone apps will open the external browser (i.e. Safari) to see the video page, but I don't know how can by pass the authentication (i.e. user should not see login form) if user already logged in the app within 15 mins.

Many thanks for your attention.

Comment: if user is not logged in then you can pass "blank"(null) with url like http://myhost.net/home.aspx?username=&password= so user won't get log in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re: August

About question 2, "[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urls];"

In theory you can do it for non-video streaming hyperlinks, but there are no solution or workaround for video streaming in similar passthough scenario.

Please also see:
[Stream MP4 Video From Seek Position in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843166/stream-mp4-video-from-seek-position-in-asp-net/11406593#11406593)

Both handler or REST web service require header handling but that might be product limitation because no existing APIs work for it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As far as your question is concern, you can only pass variables to a web url if and only if you a Web Service like REST or SOAP installed on your local or remote server. You can search for Web Service API's for ASP.net that suits your need. From there, you can authenticate any variables by setting the response in every request. You can start with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692/possible-to-create-rest-web-service-with-asp-net-2-0).

On the other end (in the iphone), you can't just use your code above to send request, this can be done using the native iOS url connection but I do recommend to use libraries like [RESTKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) or probably ASIHTTPRequest. Both handle requests like get, post, delete and update.

Comment: I 'm using REST and ASIHTTPRequest for file listing and document download. But for video streaming, html 5 webpage developed and already exists for mobile access, I want to reuse the page, but I want to bypass the authentication if the page is opened by the apps...

Comment: If you don't have an address bar in your webview, you can create specific pages that only viewable in the app I suppose.

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urls];
this line make your user exit from your application, better use web view inside your app, this is recommended.